# Grass algorithm r.neighbors doesn't work in Qgis 3.4. How can I solve this?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, error, r.neighbor

When I try to run the algorithm it gives me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 411, in processAlgorithm Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands,
>   feedback, self.outputCommands) File
>   "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py",
>   line 372, in executeGrass for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
>   File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
>   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> **UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 50: invalid continuation byte**

[image]

Comment: It seems other GRASS tools are also facing this error...

Comment: Having a similar issue trying to run r.report. QGis v 3.4 installed on Win10 using the standalone QGis installer (64bits)

Comment: Look there https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302457/qgis-3-4-error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe8-in-position-50-invalid-cont/302526#302526

Comment: This is due to a known bug, I posted a workaround on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302446/error-using-v-clean/303568#303568