# GRASS r.slope.aspect via QGIS 2.18 vs QGIS 3.4 - not working

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2, qgis-3

I seem to be unable to replicate actions with GRASS tools when I access them through QGIS 3.4. In particular the r.slope tool. I receive error messages and it fails in QGIS 3.4.
They seem to work fine when accessed via QGIS 2.18.
Is QGIS 3.4 known for such issues?
I run Windows 10.

```
***2018-12-18T00:08:30     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 413, in processAlgorithm
          Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 411, in executeGrass
          startupinfo=si if isWindows() else None
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
          restore_signals, start_new_session)
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
          startupinfo)
          OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect***
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/303568)  that may be useful. Please add the error log in the question.

Comment: I've already upgraded to 3.4.2 - the problem is still in 3.4.2.

Comment: I've added the error log????

Comment: That error [was reported](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20277) affecting vector GRASS tools of QGIS 3.4.0 on multi layer source files, but [already solved](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/repository/revisions/f65c845f86a9742602b72584b34b6ae63ed30dd7). But your error is generated under different conditions (raster layer and QGIS 3.4.2)? The tool that fails is r.slope.aspect? (There is no GRASS tool called only r.slope). I do not have that error in QGIS 3.4.2.. Can you re-produce it in a new project and loading a single raster layer?

Comment: GIS version - 3.4.2-Madeira. Yes, the tool in this version is r.slope.aspect. I've loaded a clean raster into an empty project and I get an error .

Comment: If it's not a problem with the raster files, I'd think it's a problem updating the libraries. Probably those of GRASS. I run _QGIS Desktop 3.4.2 with GRASS 7.4.2_ on a Win10 64bits machine and I have no errors in the GRASS tools, at least with the raster files that I am working with. I installed it from the _OSGeo4W Network Installer_ downloaded from the [QGIS website](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html). If you want you can try a new clean installation to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: I installed from the Standalone installers from OSGeo4W packages - version 3.4 64bit. Thanks @Gabriel.

Comment: The same problem is experienced with QGIS 3.2.  The raster file is described as "Elevation  SRTM30 dataset. CGIAR-SRTM data aggregated to 30 seconds  CGIAR SRTM (3 seconds resolution)  Grid  30 seconds"

Comment: Did a clean install of 3.4.2 @GabrielDeLuca , I'm still getting error. I suppose I need to wait until the next upgrade.

Comment: Do you have a link from which I can download the image that r.slope.aspect does not allow you to analyze? I have no errors in the GRASS tools.

Comment: The file can be found here @GabrielDeLuca - http://mbf.cc/Sovw8o

Comment: 2018-12-22T11:24:09     WARNING    Failed to load C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS 3.4/apps/qgis/plugins/grassrasterprovider7.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis\plugins\grassrasterprovider7.dll: The specified module could not be found.)  - Something not loading??

Comment: Yes. All is fine with that raster, I can process its slope. But I'm running the _qgis-bin-g7.exe_ file, and I would think that you are running the _qgis-bin.exe_ file. Serach for the bin folder. You need to run _QGIS with GRASS_ .

Comment: I've cleaned out ALL remnants of QGIS entries in the Registry. Clean installed 3.4.2-Madeira, and **still the GRASS tools fail**. Though GDAL, SAGA tools are accessible. I also made sure I ran the qgis-bin-g7.exe file as suggested @GabrielDeLuca.

Comment: As an alternative, try the OSGEO4w -non-standalone- Setup to get QGIS, GRASS and SAGA in a folder without blanks in paths.

Comment: I've now done that @AndreJ. I will test it out. In principle, this should be a 'cleaner' approach to installations.