# Unable to get QGIS 3.4 to work correctly with a clean install - Windows Registry Remnants

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I installed QGIS 3.4 and I keep getting errors attempting to use certain tools. [GRASS r.slope.aspect via QGIS 2.18 vs QGIS 3.4 - not working](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306342/grass-r-slope-aspect-via-qgis-2-18-vs-qgis-3-4-not-working) 
I uninstalled but it is not removing all traces of the software to allow a completely clean re-install. I am left with remnants in the Windows 10 Registry for various plugins. Is this what causes my problems? These entries should not be there.
[image]

[image]

---

It seems to be that on Windows 10 systems:
A. 3.4.2-Madeira (released 23/11/18) has issues interacting with the GRASS tools.
B. 3.4.3-Madeira (released 21/12/18) has issues interacting with the GRASS, SAGA tools.

Comment: I've since cleaned out ALL remnants of QGIS entries in the Registry. Clean installed 3.4.2-Madeira, and still the GRASS tools fail. Though GDAL, SAGA tools are accessible.

Comment: Re-installed, with what turned out to be 3.4.3-Madeira, and GRASS & SAGA tools are once again not accessible.