# Grass-v.buffer error

Tags: grass-gis, buffer, qgis-3

I want to create oval buffers 450 by 350 m tilted by 45° using the `v.buffer`-tool from the GUI.

When I enter everything necessary and click run, in return I get the following error message (same pops up for other Grass-algorithms):

> 2019-01-29T11:56:21     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 415, in processAlgorithm Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
>
> File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 372, in executeGrass for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
>
> File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 81: invalid start byte

A possible reason could be the following warning I get upon startup of QGis (it doesn't pop up, but it is written in the protocol):

> 2019-01-29T11:43:18     WARNING    Konnte
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin7.dll nicht laden
> (Grund: Die Bibliothek
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\plugins\grassplugin7.dll kann nicht
> geladen werden: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
>
> 2019-01-29T11:43:18     WARNING    Konnte
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/plugins/grassprovider7.dll nicht laden
> (Grund: Die Bibliothek
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\plugins\grassprovider7.dll kann nicht
> geladen werden: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)
>
> 2019-01-29T11:43:18     WARNING    Konnte
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/plugins/grassrasterprovider7.dll nicht
> laden (Grund: Die Bibliothek
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\qgis\plugins\grassrasterprovider7.dll kann
> nicht geladen werden: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.)

Basically it says "GRASS wasn't installed". So, how do I solve this? Just reinstall QGis?

Comment: check what [@gHupf](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/116276/ghupf) has answered in this thread [Error using grass v.clean: “ 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte… ”](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302446/error-using-grass-v-clean-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte)

Comment: Update to 3.4.4 solved the problem, thanks for pointing me to that question.