# QGIS 3.4 error: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 50: invalid continuation byte

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have the following error message every time I try to run a GRASS algorithm in QGIS 3.4. I unistalled the software and installed it again but I did not solve anything.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 415, in processAlgorithm
Grass7Utils.executeGrass(self.commands, feedback, self.outputCommands)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py", line 372, in executeGrass
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 50: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Similar topic [Error using v.clean](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302446/error-using-v-clean#comment487258_302446)

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue. Luckily, the answer provided by Mike worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151286)

Answer (score 5):

Try adjusting the file:
..\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Utils.py at line
370:

```
        startupinfo=si if isWindows() else None,
        encoding = 'cp850' if isWindows() else None # new encoding for DOS
) as proc:
```

400:

```
            startupinfo=si if isWindows() else None,
            encoding = 'cp850' if isWindows() else None # new encoding for DOS
    ) as proc:
```

Background: 
The console (stdout, stderr) speaks "DOS". An MSDOS non ASCII char in the output causes the code to crash.

Note:
In https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7
there is a new Version.
If also an "decode" error occurs in the new version, it is probably due to a faulty GRASS installation.
Check the grass74.bat file.

Comment: I'm not encountering an error anymore, after adjusting the code. But know QGIS gets stuck. Always after the logfile says: "No attribute table was found [...] x features without category were written". Even though an attribute table exists and it also happens with different inputs.

Comment: Try my new Adaptation´. You can also try the new Version on  https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/grass7.

Comment: Now the processing plugin can't be loaded due to a syntax error. I think it points to the word encoding.

Comment: Is there a ticket tracking this issue?

Comment: yes please, create also a QGIS issue we can't rely on a third party platform as stackexchange the trace of a bugfix

Comment: There is already an existing QGIS issue. Therefore it is an error with regional language settings. Switching the language to English (US) solves the problem. I tried it and everything worked fine, no more errors.

Answer (score 1):

**QGIS version 3.4.2:**

The new QGIS version 3.4.2 fixes this bug. You should not encounter any more error messages.

Note: This only works since QGIS version 3.4.2, if you use a previous version of 3.x please update QGIS or check the other answer(s) for possible workarounds.