# Error when running SAGA interpolation

Tags: qgis, raster, saga

I am running the nearest neighbour algorithm in QGIS 3.4.3.
[image]

I have tried various parameters but the problem persists. I have also tried other algorithms (simple Kriging) and had the same problem. However, I did succed running the IDW interpolation algorithm from the QGIS plugin itself.

this is the message log :

[image]

Comment: That field name looks very odd... is it correct?

Comment: @ndawson yes, the field title is strange, maybe because I worked on the project using a different version of QGIS, but its contents are real numbers to 5 d.p. ranging from 15 to 21. I re-installed QGIS using OSGeo4W, and I am having no problems, all the interpolation tools of SAGA are working fine!

Comment: looks like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302457/qgis-3-4-error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe8-in-position-50-invalid-cont/302526#302526

Comment: Please show the lines of code around the line 113 from the file SagaUtils.py