# QGIS Raster merging UnicodeDecodeError: invalid start byte

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, error

Edit: I moved them to another folder so that the file path is shorter, but the problem still isn't solved unfortunately..

I Tried merging two Raster Layers (Digital surface models), but that's the output I get. Does anyone know what the problem is?

QGIS Version: 3.16.4-Hannover

````
Input parameters:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : ['C:/Users/jonas/Documents/UMEP_energyyearroof/0_alle/Energyyearroof_10.tif','C:/Users/jonas/Documents/UMEP_energyyearroof/0_alle/Energyyearroof_11.tif'], 'NODATA_INPUT' : None, 'NODATA_OUTPUT' : -9999, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PCT' : False, 'SEPARATE' : False }

GDAL command:
python3 -m gdal_merge -a_nodata -9999 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o C:/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_gYGbnK/4f8b13ee82e04fe493639dcfc8ab471d/OUTPUT.tif --optfile C:/Users/jonas/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_gYGbnK/1e7ec3ef9602404c998dee96f23658ee/mergeInputFiles.txt
GDAL command output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 138, in processAlgorithm
GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.16/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 108, in runGdal
for line in proc.stdout:
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 236: invalid start byte

Execution failed after 0.45 seconds```
````

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue in a path to your input, can you please show them?

Comment: @Taras It's the path at work, I'm not allowed to unfortunately. But one folder in the path has a space in it instead of ```_```, could this be the reason?

Comment: I assume that it could be a reason. Try some additional workarounds demonstrated in these threads: [1] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302446/error-using-grass-v-clean-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte [2] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302457/qgis-3-4-error-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xe8-in-position-50-invalid-cont [3] https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301009/grass-algorithm-r-neighbors-doesnt-work-in-qgis-3-4-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @Taras I edited my question - unfortunately my  guess wasn't right, it didn't solve the problem - but now you can see the filepath, maybe you got another idea?

Comment: Also maybe you can find something useful in these issue-tickets: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31023 and https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1067